# With Facebook Open Graph in sandbox mode, should actions I post as admin show on my wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to work with Facebook Open Graph. I've defined an app. I've set up an action and an object ("cook" and "recipe"). I've put up a web page for one of the objects, which includes all the metadata required. I'm now trying to post some test items on my wall using cURL (with the sample commands that it gives you when you click Get Code by the action on the open graph setup page).

When I just issue a command to "cook" a "recipe", without also adding a comment or anything, then the command seems to work, and I can view the returned ID in the debugger. On my profile, the item appears in the right-hand sidebar, but not on my wall or in my own newsfeed.

When I issue a command to cook a recipe, and also give it a user-generated photograph, again the command seems to work and returns an ID, again I can view that ID in the debugger and it looks fine, but this one doesn't appear anywhere: not in the sidebar, not in the news feed, not on my wall.

Permissions-wise, I'm using my own user account, which is an admin account for the app. On the App Center tab of the developer site, my app has `publish_actions` under "User & Friend Permissions" in the "Permissions" section.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
curl -F 'access_token=<token>' 
-F 'recipe=<urlOfRecipe>' 
-F 'image[0][url]=<urlOfUserImage>' 
-F 'image[0][user_generated]=true' 
-F 'message=Look at my cake!' 
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/mynamespace:cook'
```

So what's the deal? Is it not working because I'm in sandbox mode? (I assumed that sandbox mode stuff would still show up to me, just not to anyone else.) Is it because the action hasn't been approved yet? Or am I doing something wrong?

Does it make a difference that my personal profile is not using Facebook Timeline?

How can I know that, when this is all live, my app will be able to post things that will appear on users' news feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should all appear in your activity log, but distribution of Open Graph actions is low compared to aggressive publishing like feed stories.

Without Timeline, most of the distribution is likely lost as there's no aggregation units on timeline, and news feed distribution of a single action is unlikely, but your calls should definitely result in something appearing in your activity log and the post ID you get back should be retrievable from the API to verify the details at `/ACTION_ID`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Given that our brief was to allow the user to take a photo of something they cooked and share it on Facebook, would you suggest going the Open Graph route, or would you think that just uploading the photo then posting a wall post would be better? I like the metadata inherent in this solution, but it's only good if it gets seen often enough.

Comment: If it's a single photo per user, news feed may be better. If it's many, definitely use open graph or you'll hit spam filters pretty quickly, the primary sources of distribution for OG actions are in ticker, timeline aggregations, and news feed stories. OG stories with photos attached get better distribution than generic stories, but the rules for those getting approved are stricter (sounds like your app is an appropriate use-case though)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've just run into this - are you getting an error like this?

```
{"error"=>{
  "code"=>1611165,
  "type"=>"Exception",
  "message"=>"Application with ID 179189035473500 has not been
              granted the capability to use the property message."}}
```

If you remove the message param, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function that you're looking for here is [explicit sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/explicit-sharing/).

This is a subset of the Open Graph functionality that allows you to post feed stories as first-order items.  Like the page says, it's not for everything, but seems right for photos that a user wants to intentionally share.

As I understand it, these Open Graph stories will actually get *more* visibility than a standard feed post, since they can be treated as separate objects.

If the posting is happening automatically though (depending on UI flow), a certain action might not be approved for explicit sharing permissions.